# assign values of one dataframe column to another dataframe column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

am trying to compare two dataframes based on different columns and assign a value to a dataframe based on it.

df1 :

```
date    value1  value2
4/1/2021    A   1
4/2/2021    B   2
4/6/2021    C   3
4/4/2021    D   4
4/5/2021    E   5
4/6/2021    F   6
4/2/2021    G   7
```

df2:

```
Date    percent
4/1/2021    0.1
4/2/2021    0.2
4/6/2021    0.6
```

output:

```
date    value1  value2  per
4/1/2021    A   1       0.1
4/2/2021    B   2       0.2
4/6/2021    C   3       0.6
4/4/2021    D   4       0
4/5/2021    E   5       0
4/6/2021    F   6       0
4/2/2021    G   7       0.2
```

Code1:

```
df1['per'] = np.where(df1['date']==df2['Date'], df2['per'], 0)
```

error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Note: changed the column value of df2['Date] to df2['date] and then tried merging
code2:

```
new = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['date'], how='inner')
```

error:

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and datetime64[ns] columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

Comment: The merge is likely the best approach for this. You probably want to have `how='left' ` thought.  The error is because your date columns are different data types, one is object (likely strings) and the other is datetime. If you convert one of the columns to match the other, (make them both object or both datetime) the merge should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1['per']=df1['date'].map(dict(zip(df2['Date'], df2['percent']))).fillna(0)



      date value1  value2  per
0  4/1/2021      A       1  0.1
1  4/2/2021      B       2  0.2
2  4/6/2021      C       3  0.6
3  4/4/2021      D       4  0.0
4  4/5/2021      E       5  0.0
5  4/6/2021      F       6  0.6
6  4/2/2021      G       7  0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pd.merge` and perform a `left` join to keep all the rows from `df1` and bring over all the date matching rows from `df2`:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on='date',right_on='Date', how='left').fillna(0).drop('Date',axis=1)
```

Prints:

```
         date value1  value2  percent
0  04/01/2021      A       1      0.1
1  04/02/2021      B       2      0.2
2  04/06/2021      C       3      0.6
3  04/04/2021      D       4      0.0
4  04/05/2021      E       5      0.0
5  04/06/2021      F       6      0.6
6  04/02/2021      G       7      0.2
```

*I think there's a typo on your penultimate row. `percent` should be 0.6 IIUC.