# Copy one dataframe column value to another using condition in scala

Tags: mysql, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

DF1:

| accountID | cost |
| --- | --- |
| act1 | 100 |
| act2 | 150 |

DF2:

| accountID | serviceType | region | date | cost | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| act1 | s1 | us-east-1 | 2022-07-01 | 20 |  |
| act1 | s1 | us-east-1 | 2022-07-02 | 50 |  |
| act1 | s1 | us-east-1 | 2022-07-30 | 100 |  |
| act2 | s1 | us-east-1 | 2022-07-01 | 100 |  |
| act2 | s1 | us-east-1 | 2022-07-30 | 150 |  |

excepted output: when accountID is matched between dataframes, output column should be value filled from DF1

| accountID | serviceType | region | date | cost | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| act1 | s1 | us-east-1 | 2022-07-01 | 20 | 100 |
| act1 | s1 | us-east-1 | 2022-07-02 | 50 | 100 |
| act1 | s1 | us-east-1 | 2022-07-30 | 100 | 100 |
| act2 | s1 | us-east-1 | 2022-07-01 | 100 | 150 |
| act2 | s1 | us-east-1 | 2022-07-30 | 150 | 150 |

I tried with withColumn and joins but it is not working.

```
val outputDF = df2.withColumn("output",when(col("accountID") === partitionedDf("accountID"),partitionedDf("cost")))
```

related post in python however I want it in scala.
[assign values of one dataframe column to another dataframe column based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70004051/assign-values-of-one-dataframe-column-to-another-dataframe-column-based-on-condi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `join` is what you are looking for.
Its purpose is exactly to merge related data from different tables/datasets.

```scala
df1.join(df2.withColumnRenamed("cost", "output"), "accountID")
```

Since in both `df1` and `df2` you have a column `cost` and you want the `df2.cost` to be renamed into `output`, it is convenient (but not required) to do it before the join (`df2.withColumnRenamed("cost", "output")`).

In this case a left join is used (the default, since not specified) and the join condition is the equality of the `accountID` column.